# Introduction to approximate message passing

Tags: inference, graphical-model, bayesian-network, approximate-inference, belief-propagation

I'm interested in learning approximate message passing from the paper "Message Passing Algorithms for Compressed Sensing: I. Motivation and Construction". My background is in computer science and engineering and I have never taken a course on measure theory.

I've noticed that the paper mentioned above requires knowledge in measure theory. So I searched for resources and I found this [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf) which I still find it based on pure mathematics.

Can anyone recommend a readable introduction or papers that are prerequisites to the sources above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [Structured Belief Propagation for NLP](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Emgormley/bp-tutorial/bp-tutorial.pdf) (especially starting from Section 2) is a wonderful resource that could fit your background.

The slides offer plenty of illustrations and elementary examples. They are very close to what you would actually program.

Comment: It's really good reference you provided. But it still doesn't explain some lemmas in the reference "Message Passing Algorithms for Compressed Sensing: I. Motivation and Construction".